# How check if first digit of integer is zero in python

Tags: python, string, integer

** i want to check if first digit of integer is zero.
If it is zero, i want to leave first digit which is zero and take the rest.
For example num = 0618861552
In this case first digit is zero. I want to get 618861552

If the first digit of num is not zero, i want to take the entire string.

For example num = 618861552
In this case first digit of num is not zero, i want to get 618861552

Below is the code i have tried.

Note that my code works if first digit is not zero but doesn't work if the first digit is zero
**

```
num =  int(input("enter number: "))

#changing int to str to index.

position  = str(num)

if int(position[0]) == 0:
    len = len(position)
    position1 = position[1:len] 
    print(position1)
else:
    len = len(position)
    position1 = position [0:len]
    print(position1)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
number = input("enter number: ")
print(number.lstrip('0'))
```

Comment: Bro didn't understand. Where do i use this code in?

Comment: `lstrip()` method removes any leading characters. I have updated my answer! That's your whole code

Answer (score 0):

This would work :

```py
def remove_zero (a) :
    a = str(a)
    if ord(a[0]) == 48 :
        a = a[1:]
    return (str(a))

p = int(input("Enter a number :"))
q = remove_zero(p)
print(q)
```

Comment: Bro it worked nice. Thanks for reply. Real programmer much thanks to you   ❤

Comment: One more thing what is ord mean in your code why using == 48.

Comment: ord is a function that is used to return the unicode (ASCII Value) of a character.

Comment: Ascii Value of Zero and unicode for zero ('0') is same....But ascii value and unicode are two different things

Comment: If i want to remove another number like 6 or 5 would this function work for me and how?  Would mind giving your WhatsApp number for more learning bro 

Answer (score 0):

Actually converting to int remove all leading zero.

```
num = "0020"
num2 = "070"
num3 = "000000070"
print(int(num))
print(int(num2))
print(int(num3))
```

Output is

```
20
70
70
```

And this way works too:

```
num = int(input())
print(num)
```

That is why

> Note that my code works if first digit is not zero but doesn't work if
> the first digit is zero **

It is always without leading zero after convertion to int

Comment: Broh thank you so much. It worked fine like i wanted. No need to check the first digit if it is 0 in integer. Converting to int will remove leading zeros. Much thanks to you.